# basis of space of all $3\times3$ matrices and basis of space of all $3\times3$ matrices with rank $0, 1$ or $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have a set of all $3\times3$ matrices $B$ that have rank $0, 1$ or $2$ - what is the basis of a subspace that this set generates?

I came to the conclusion that this subspace consists of lines, planes and the null vector and it generates the whole space of $\Bbb R^3$, but I don't know what is the basis of this subspace - is it just the set of all the $B$'s?

EDIT: my original thinking was very wrong, the questions I ended up with are what is the basis of the space of all $3\times3$ matrices and what is the basis of the subspace - all $3\times3$ matrices with rank $0, 1$ or $2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector space of all $3 x 3$ matrices is not $R^3$. You can verify that the space has dimension $9$ because you will need $9$ vectors for a basis. Probably the most likely ones would be $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0  & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1  & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ ... $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  & 0\\1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0  & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Now considering that your subspace only contains matrices with rank $\leq2$ the basis for that space will contain only $6$ of these $9$.

Comment: SInce all those matrices have rank $\le2$, they all belong to the given set.

Comment: Is that true? Taking linear combinations of all $9$ will yield all possible matrices, including rank $3$ ones. If we leave out the ones that have 1's in the last column ofr instance, all combinations will have rank $\leq2$ , or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, *every* matrix belongs to the span of the rank $1$ matrices.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. As I understand it, OP is looking for a basis of the subspace of $3x3$ matrices that do not include the ones with rank$3$. I believe you could find a basis in this manner. But if I am wrong I'd like to learn as well !

Comment: I don't really understand why the vector space of all 3x3 matrices has dimension 9? can someone please explain?

Comment: I edited and drawn all $9$. If you take linear combinations you can make all $3x3$ matrices, but remove one you and will find that you can no longer do that (one position will remain always zero.) If you create a set with for example all 1' in the first row and remove the first 3 then you will find you can also no longer create all matrices. Play around with this idea and you will notice that you will always need at least of $9$ matrices to be able to create all of them, in other words to span the space. Each matrix is a vector in this space. And they have to be independent to form a basis.

Comment: N.P. Maybe it's a good idea to edit the title so that it reflects the question better (not generating all of $R^3$) for other people looking for answers. Also, if the answer turns out to be the one you're looking for please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear which space you're talking about---subspace of what? If you are viewing $3\times3$ matrices as elements of $V=\mathbb R^{3,3}$ i.e. $3\times3$ matrices under addition, then the answer is all of $V$.

Comment: the set of B matrices is the subspace of R^3

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: the whole task was that I have two 3x3 matrices: A and C - A has rank 2 and C can be any 3x3 matrix and the question is: what is the basis of a subspace of the space of all 3x3 matrices that is generated by the set of 3x3 matrices B that satisfy the equation A*C=B (I'm trying to translate it into english as exact as I can)

Comment: maybe I'm interpreting the phrase "the space of all 3x3 matrices" wrongly, I thought it is just R^3 but maybe it's something else?

Comment: The space of all 3x3 matrices *acts on* $\mathbb R^3$ but it is not of itself $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: ok... so I have a three-dimensional space (the space of all 3x3 matrices) that is NOT R^3 and then the subspace of that space (the set of all matrices B) which consists of lines, planes and the null vector is that right?

Comment: @agromek The problem you have is very different from the one in the question. You're basically asked to find the image of the linear map $C\mapsto AC$, with domain and codomain the vector space of $3\times3$ matrices.